# OracleBulkCopy from a text file - how to set primary key

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, odp.net

I'm attempting to use OracleBulkCopy to read large delimited files into a single table. The primary key is column ID and defined as number(20,0) which, I believe, nHibernate normally increments via sequence upon insert. If I use oracleBulkCopy via odp.net, how do I ensure the ID is incremented upon insert AND not having concurrency issues when others are inserting via the application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sequence in oracle so it can increment automatically your id

CREATE SEQUENCE **MY_TABLE_SEQ** INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE NOMINVALUE NOCYCLE NOCACHE NOORDER;

CREATE TRIGGER **MY_TABLE_INSERT_TRIGGER** BEFORE INSERT ON **MY_TABLE**
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT **MY_TABLE_SEQ**.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.**MY_ID_FIELD** FROM DUAL;
END;

Answer (score 0):

The answer is incorrect.

Triggers need to be disabled when using OracleBulkCopy.

http://ora-26086.ora-code.com/